# How to calculate sum of this series modulo m fast?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, modular-arithmetic

so I came across this problem where I need to calculate this:

1<sup>k</sup>+(1+p)<sup>k</sup>+(1+2*p)<sup>k</sup>+.....+(1+n*p)<sup>k</sup> % p

Where p is prime and k is some number strictly less than p.

p is less than 500 and n*p could range upto 10<sup>9</sup>

The only solution I could think is iterate from first to last term and calculate the modulo using exponentiation but that would be too costly I am looking for a faster algorithm.

Is it possible to do it faster?

Comment: @JohnColeman ohh my! Not exactly a homework, but looks like I didn't think enough.

Comment: @JohnColeman looks like it, can I accept a comment as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any integer `m`, `(1+m*p)^k % p == 1`.

Thus, computing

```
(1^k + (1+2*p)^k  + (1+3*p)^k + ... + (1+n*p)^k )% p
```

is the same as computing

```
(1 + 1 + 1 ... + 1) % p
```

Where there are `n + 1` terms in the parentheses.

The answer is thus `(n + 1)%p`.

Comment: I can't imagine someone having a faster algorithm than that! :P

Comment: There are n+1 terms.